# GetEnvironmentVariable doesnt work in Inno Setup (Delphi)

Tags: environment-variables, inno-setup, pascalscript

Hi I'm using Inno Setup (Delphi based) for my installer I am working on. All I want is to put the username in a String:
My code:

```
var
usrname: string;
begin
usrname := GetEnvironmentVariable('USERNAME');
end;
```

When I'm trying to compile my code, there is allways this error message:

> Unknown identifier 'GetEnvironmentVariable'

What am I doing wrong? Im new in delphi so the correct way might be obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called [`GetEnv`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getenv.htm) in Inno Setup, so fix your code e.g. this way:

```
var
  UserName: string;
begin
  UserName := GetEnv('USERNAME');
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the environment for this task is the wrong solution, as the environment is hackable.  Simply use the support function [`GetUserNameString`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getusernamestring.htm).

(Also note that normally you should not need to use the username during an install, and that it might not be the one you really wanted if the installer is running elevated.  But those are separate topics.)

Comment: Thx for your comment. For case I need the username because my setup repaces a file in the Home dir.

Comment: 1. Admin installers cannot reliably touch files in the home dirs anyway, so don't do that.  Leave it to your application startup.

2. Unless it's directly in the top-level profile folder itself (which you shouldn't be using), you should be using one of the standard constants instead, such as `{userappdata}`.